# Why there is text extra text in the table of contents heading

Tags: table-of-contents, books

Here i am facing with the extra text appears in the table of content heading, How do i solve the problem Here is my MWE

```
 \documentclass[twoside,8pt,openany]{book}
  \usepackage[inner=1cm,outer=0.5cm,paperheight=9.5in,paperwidth=6.3in]{geometry}

  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{titletoc} %%% Table of contents 
  \usepackage{ebgaramond}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
  \usepackage{paracol}
  \usepackage{microtype}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark} %% display chapter in header
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
    \fancyhead[C]{\thepage} %% To display numbering on every page alternately left and right

  \setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
  \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
  \setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
  \usepackage[colorlinks, unicode]{hyperref}

  %%%% End Add
  \makeatletter
  \newcommand\versenumcolor{red}
  \newcommand\chapnumcolor{red}
  \renewcommand\paragraph{%
    \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                  {.25ex \@plus.25ex \@minus.1ex}%
                  {-.5em}%
                  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{\versenumcolor}}}%
  \newlength{\biblechapskip}
    \setlength{\biblechapskip}{1em plus .33em minus .2em}
  \newcounter{biblechapter}
  \newcounter{bibleverse}[biblechapter]
  \renewcommand\chaptername{Book}
  \let\ltx@chapter=\chapter
  \let\ltx@paragraph=\paragraph
  \newcommand{\book}[1]{%
    \gdef\currbook{#1}
    \ltx@chapter{#1}}
  \newcount\biblechap@svdopt
  \newenvironment{biblechapter}[1][\thebiblechapter]
    {\biblechap@svdopt=#1
    \ifnum\c@biblechapter=\biblechap@svdopt\else
      \advance\biblechap@svdopt by -1\fi
    \setcounter{biblechapter}{\the\biblechap@svdopt}
    \refstepcounter{biblechapter}
    \lettrine{\color{\chapnumcolor}\lower-6pt\hbox{\thebiblechapter}}{}\ignorespaces}
    {\vspace{\biblechapskip}}
  \renewcommand{\verse}[1][\thebibleverse]{%
    \refstepcounter{bibleverse}
    \markright{{\scshape\currbook} \thebiblechapter:\thebibleverse}
    \ifnum\c@bibleverse=1\else
      \ltx@paragraph*{#1}\fi}%
  \makeatother


  \newcounter{jChapter} 

 \newcommand{\jverse}[1]{\noindent{\fontsize{11}{30}\selectfont\color{cyan}\textbf{#1\hspace{1.0mm}}\noindent}\markboth{\scshape \currbook\ \thejChapter : #1}{} }

 \newcommand{\jChapter}[1]{
   \setcounter{jChapter}{#1}
   \noindent{\fontsize{27}{30}\selectfont\color{red}\textbf{#1}}\markboth{\scshape \currbook\ \thejChapter : 1}{}%\vspace{-5mm}
  }     
  \newcommand{\story}[1]{\vfill\noindent\parbox[t]{\columnwidth}{\centering\it\color{blue}\textbf{#1}}}% \centering contained within \parbox

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \newcommand{\storygap}{\vfill\ensurevspace{3\baselineskip}\switchcolumn*}% paracol specific code
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

  \title{\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont\textbf{KARBI - NRSV PARALLEL BIBLE}}
  \date{}
  \author{}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage{ragged2e}
  \newcommand{\BookLine}{ \centering\noindent\rule{19cm}{1pt}}
  \newcommand{\BookNote}[1]{{\begin{center} \textbf{KEPACHINI} \justify

  #1
  \end{center}
  \BookLine
  \vspace{2mm}
  }}

  \newcommand{\ParallelLText}[2]{\switchcolumn[0] #1\par \switchcolumn[1] #2\par \switchcolumn*}

  \usepackage[perpage]{footmisc} %%% To restart footnote numbering on every new pages

  \usepackage{multicol,etoolbox}

  \setcounter{tocdepth}{2} %set depth of printed table of contets.

  \makeatletter


  \patchcmd{\l@section}
    {\hfil}
    {\leaders\hbox{\normalfont$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep     mu$}\hfill}
    {}{}

  \renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
      \begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\contentsname
          \@mkboth{%
             \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}]%
      \printlist{toc}{}{}
      \thispagestyle{empty}
      \end{multicols}%
      }

  \makeatother %print dots in sections in toc.


 %%% Command to make uppercase for every first letter
 \usepackage{mfirstuc}
 \MFUnocap{are}
 \MFUnocap{or}
 \MFUnocap{etc}

 \newcommand{\athepi}{\textbf{\capitalisewords{Athepi Alamthe Hei Hei}}\\}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{transparent}


 \begin{document}
 \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\emph{\alph{footnote}}}


 \frontmatter
 \maketitle
 {\setlength{\columnsep}{130pt}
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\Huge Kechejok Barim\hfill~\\[2.5ex] }
 \startlist{toc}
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
 \tableofcontents
 }
 \mainmatter

 {\pagenumbering{gobble}
 \part*{\scshape Kechejok Barim}
 }
 \pagenumbering{arabic}  
   \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
 \setcounter{page}{1}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}
 \book{Kecheng}

 \end{document}
```

Output of the above MWE is shown below
[image]

But when i change the paper format to A4Paper size it comes correctly it shown below
[image]

How do i achive my corrected page without changing my paper sizes?

Comment: Didn't you mention a minimal working example?

Comment: I have mentioned my MWE @Johannes_B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy solved. Just put a `\thispagestyle{empty}` or `\thispagestyle{plain}` before the command `\tableofcontents`. It is the text in the running header that overlaps the title, because you have so narrow header.

I have not bothered to repeat all your code, I only copied the snippet where you have to enter the command. Of course, you can do the same in more sophisticated ways.

However, I recommend you, instead of all the hacking you have done to the book class, use a class like [scrbook](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrbook) from [KOMA-script](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), where you can make all you changes with built in commands. You will then avoid all the incompatibilities you will experience.

If you prefer the original bookclass, I recommend you to use a bundle of packages from the same author. The author of [enumitem](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), [Javier Bezos López](https://ctan.org/author/bezos) , has also produced excellent packages that change page styles, heading, table of contents *etc*. Have a look at [titleps](https://ctan.org/pkg/titleps) (page style control), [titlesec](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) (alternative section titles) and [titletoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) (alternative headings for toc/lof/lot). And last, but not least, [colorspace](https://ctan.org/pkg/colorspace), if you prefer that your colours prints correctly.

[image]

```
 \frontmatter
 \maketitle
 {\setlength{\columnsep}{130pt}
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\Huge Kechejok Barim\hfill~\\[2.5ex] }
 \startlist{toc}
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
 \thispagestyle{plain}\tableofcontents  %% <--- Change code here
 }
 \mainmatter
```